# derived column does not exist in hibernate entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

```
SELECT id,zipcode,state_id,district_city_id,city_id,country_id,longitude,latitude,region,post_office,( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( ? ) ) * cos( radians(Latitude) ) * cos( radians( Longitude ) - radians( ? ) ) + sin( radians( ? ) ) * sin( radians( Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM zipcodeinfo group by city_id HAVING distance < ? order by distance asc
```

here i want a distance filed which is derived from current input and table data .
But this is saying that distance does not exist even i have created a transient variable as distance .

Comment: you do know that "cos", "radians", "sin", etc are not valid keywords/functions in JPQL? JPQL != SQL. Also JPQL depends on classes/fields and you haven't posted the entity class

Answer (score 0):

you use distance in your query in the having clause

```
HAVING distance < ?
```

and in the order clause

```
order by distance
```

But distance is transient as you say, is not a column in the database, hence you cannot use it on having and order clause because a column of the table is expected